# TreeMap properties(Hierarchy, Size by) using ironpython script in spotfire

Tags: ironpython, treemap, spotfire

How can I change TreeMap properties(Hierarchy, Size by) using ironpython script in spotfire.

Comment: -1 where have you looked so far? What have you tried so far? Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for advice on how to ask questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import Treemap
treeChart = vis.As[Treemap]()
vis.Title="tree map title"
treeChart.Data.DataTableReference = "Your Expression"
treeChart.ColorAxis.Expression = "Your Expression"
```

Comment: +1 for posting up your answer. Nicely done. You can mark your own answer as accepted and it will help other users find the solution if they have the same problem.